# Conflicting information about late recharacterizing of excess contributions

Tags: ira, roth-ira, income-tax, recharacterization

Say someone contributed more than they were allowed to for a Roth IRA in Year 1 (therefore, there was an excess contribution). Can they still re-characterize that contribution to a Traditional IRA contribution between April 15 and October 15 of Year 2?

From the [Publication 590 part on recharacterizing excess contributions](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p590/ch01.html#en_US_2012_publink1000230678), the example seems to indicate not:

> Example.
>
> You contributed more than you were entitled to in 2012. You cannot
>   recharacterize the excess contributions you made in 2012 after April
>   15, 2013, because contributions after that date are no longer timely
>   for 2012.

However, the sentences above talk about this "If you are applying excess contributions for prior years as current contributions", so it sounds like you could *not* apply excess contributions for prior years as current contributions, and then it would be okay.

The [section on extensions for recharacterizations](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p590/ch01.html#en_US_2012_publink1000230693) seems to indicate that it is okay to recharacterize between April and October for the previous year as long as the return was timely filed.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different operations going on:

- **Recharacterization**: change a contribution from one type of IRA to another type of IRA.
- **Excess Contribution**: Money was contributed that exceed the allowable limits.

They each have of a set of rules regarding amounts, timelines, taxes, and penalties. The excess money can't be recharacterized except during a specific window of time.

I would see a tax professional to work through all the details.